# Unable to see .Net Framework version menu when creating a new project on Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

[What I currently see when creating a new project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rnfy.png)
On coding tutorials there is a box to the left of sort to select the version of .net framework you want to use.

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2017 Community

Comment: That's the way it ought to be, probably a recent update of VS2017 removed it.  Use Help > About to update your question with the version number.  You don't target the desktop version of .NET in a UWP app, they always target .NETCore.

Answer (score 2):

That's a change welcome, as .NET Framework version number is meaningless for non .NET Framework project types,

- UWP
- Xamarin
- .NET Core
- .NET Standard
- and possibly others.

Screen shots in tutorials can easily go out-of-date, as VS is now patching quickly.

**Update: Should be a feature of 15.6**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.6#webtools

Answer (score 1):

That menu hasn't been there for quite some time now.

To change the .NET Framework version for your project, first create the project then go to the Solution Properties --> Application and change the "Target Framework".